# Cache feature lengths are in Web Mercator, what is the conversion factor to miles?

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry-conversion, web-mercator, operations-dashboard

I have a cache polyline feature with a Shape_Length field calculated in Web Mercator. I need to convert that feature length to feet or miles.  I am using the Value Conversion tool in Dashboards !!Indicator widget.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no straight conversion factor, since distortion is a function of latitude for the Web Mercator projection. Have you tried converting to lat/longs and getting the geodesic distance?

Comment: The shape_length value should be in meters already to conversion to (international) feet is to divide by 0.3048. As Mintx mentions, distance calculations in web Mercator aren't accurate.

Comment: thank you for the input.